# I have problem with accents (Ã§Ã£o) in potuguese with JSPDF in NODE

Tags: jspdf

I use JSPDF in Node but the examples not working with me when i use accents in portuguese. Example:

```
   var doc = new jsPDF();

doc.text("This is the default font. Accents: áéíóç", 20, 20);

doc.setFont("courier", "normal");
doc.text("This is courier normal. Accents: áéíóç", 20, 30);

doc.setFont("Times", "italic");
doc.text("Teste de acentuação. Accents: áéíóç", 20, 40);
```

The result is

```
This is the default font. Accents: Ã¡Ã©Ã-Ã³Ã§

This is courier normal. Accents: Ã¡Ã©Ã-Ã³Ã§

Teste de acentuaÃ§Ã£o. Accents: Ã¡Ã©Ã-Ã³Ã§
```

In Live preview the oficial site works, but in my computer not.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved with

```
    const doc = new jsPDF(
    {
        filters: ["ASCIIHexEncode"]
    }
);
```